# Incorrect images loading on slow connection

Tags: html, ios, image, magento

I have a Magento ecommerce site that has been in production for a couple weeks now.  This weekend I noticed that when trying to view the website on my phone that when the connection is slow there are times when images are displayed incorrectly.  There is an image in each spot I would expect an image, the problem is that at times it is not the correct image.  I have product images showing up in place of the logo and vice versa, same with images in the footer, at times I have the mastercard logo in place of a product image.  They aren't swapped (a product image in place of the logo and the logo for that particular product image). It's all random.  I've also not been able to recreate the issue twice in a row.

The only unique cases I've found here is that it only happens with slow connections, and I've only seen it happen on an iPhone.  I'm not 100% sure it only happens with iOS, that is all I've been able to test on.  It hasen't happened on a computer, but I've also not had a computer with a slow connection.
To see what the page should look like normally go to:

www.amaproflattrackmerchandise.com

Here are a couple screen shots of what I am experiencing:
[Screen Shot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDKWw.jpg)

[Screen Shot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzW5O.jpg)

Comment: It seems like css issues, use clear:both after header and try

Comment: @arshad doesnt clear:both only affect element's floating?